# a ViewModel lives longer than its factory

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I do not understand the purpose of the following method.

```
android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders.of(
  FragmentActivity activity,
  ViewModelProvider.Factory factory)
```

Suppose we have a subclass `Activity1` of `FragmentActivity`. Suppose Android created `Activity1`'s instance `a0` because a user started it, then Android created `Activity1`'s instance `a1` because the user rotated the screen, so `a0` and `a1` are the same activity from the user's view point. As far as I understand, the `of` method should be called in `Activity1.onCreate`. I also saw in [examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/ui/ProductFragment.java) that `factory` for the call is created in `Activity1.onCreate` too. Suppose that `factory0` was created in `a0.onCreate`, and `factory1` was created in `a1.onCreate`. I presume that

```
ViewModelProviders.of(a0, factory0).get(ProductViewModel.class)
```

and

```
ViewModelProviders.of(a1, factory1).get(ProductViewModel.class)
```

must return the same object reference because that object must outlive `a0` and `a1`. But how is this possible if `factory0` and `factory1` are different references?

This is not a moot question. A factory may contain a value which is written to a `ProductViewModel` instance, like `productId` in the example. Continuing with the example, if

```
factory0 = new ProductViewModel.Factory(..., 0);
factory1 = new ProductViewModel.Factory(..., 1);
```

what will the value of

```
ViewModelProviders.of(a1, factory1).get(ProductViewModel.class).mProductId
```

be, `0` or `1`? If `0`, is not this an incorrect behavior? If `1`, then, I believe, the state of the activity UI is lost, which is also bad.

Relevant code excerpts.

```
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ProductViewModel.Factory factory = new ProductViewModel.Factory(
                getActivity().getApplication(), getArguments().getInt(KEY_PRODUCT_ID));
        final ProductViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
                .get(ProductViewModel.class);
        ...
}
```

and

```
public class ProductViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private final int mProductId;
    public ProductViewModel(@NonNull Application application, DataRepository repository,
            final int productId) {
        super(application);
        mProductId = productId;
        ...
    }
    public static class Factory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {
        private final int mProductId;
        public Factory(@NonNull Application application, int productId) {
            ...
            mProductId = productId;
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) new ProductViewModel(mApplication, mRepository, mProductId);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I read your question twice what i understood if you have wrong idea how the whole activity lifeCycle work's.

> Suppose Android created Activity1's instance a0 because a user started
>   it, then Android created Activity1's instance a1 because the user
>   rotated the screen, so a0 and a1 are the same activity from the user's
>   view point.

When orientation changes the activity is destroyed and all data associated with it is also destroyed until you save it in savedPreference or ViewModel or DB.

So, in simple words the state of app is lost once the orientation is changed so there is no `a0` or `a1`.

So there is no `factory0` and `factory1`

whole app data is reseted and only saved in your viewModel as single state of app before orientation change so when your `onCreate()`  of activity run's you restore the last state of App by getting data from ViewModel using it's factory to get its instance. So in other word's the ViewModel is not destroyed, while your activity is destroyed.Just look at your ViewModel as your Db to save the state of app dynamically in the memory of device.

> be, 0 or 1? If 0, is not this an incorrect behavior? If 1, then, I
>   believe, the state of the activity UI is lost, which is also bad.

There will be no `0` or `1` ViewModel will have the last data before the orientation is changed.(you can call it as `0` i.e old data).Once the orientation is changed and you change state of app again and update your ViewModel then that is the newwState.

[image: Activity LifeCycle]

So from above Chart the Activity is Destroyed i.e the Instance of activity is destroyed.

**NOTE:** [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) is not a Part of Activity LifeCycle

Comment: There are `a0` and `a1`. `a0` and `a1` are instances of `Activity1` before and after rotation respectively.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: “whole app data is reseted and only saved in your viewModel.” This is a contradiction. If all data is reset, how comes that some data is saved? 